# Hiding days in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have some problem with hiding days in datepicker depending of day of week e.g. if today is friday hide saturday and if today is saturday - hide sunday.

I have this code who check what day is today:

```
$(function () {
var day_date = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
      weekday[0]="Sunday";
      weekday[1]="Monday";
      weekday[2]="Tuesday";
      weekday[3]="Wednesday";
      weekday[4]="Thursday";
      weekday[5]="Friday";
      weekday[6]="Saturday";
    var n = weekday[day_date.getDay()];
    $('#day_of_week').val(n);
});
```

I also have this code to hide (but whole) weekends and days who always be hidden:

```
var disabledDays = ['15/8/2012', '1/11/2012', '11/11/2012', '25/12/2012', '26/12/2012'];

function nationalDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(),
        d = date.getDate(),
        y = date.getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(d + '/' + (m + 1) + '/' + y, disabledDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
            return [false];
        }
    }
    return [true];
}

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
  var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
  return noWeekend[0] ? nationalDays(date) : noWeekend;
}
```

On datepicker the line who "execute" above code looks like this:

```
beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
```

I try to do this with this code, but it didn't work:

```
$('#day_of_week').change(function()
     if( $("#day_of_week").val() == Friday ) {
          $("#date_from, #date_to").datepicker({
          beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays
      });
      }
     else {
      }
});
```

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I am using a date picker in which it automatically work on hiding date.
I hope it will helpful to you. 
http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#maxPicks-demo

Comment: Great examples, but no example how to hide days depending on "today" day

Answer (score 1):

I got a link regarding this and hopefull it will work.
[http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)